# Prevent or dismiss 'empty file' warning in loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

My code goes through a number of files reading them into lists with the command:

```
data = np.loadtxt(myfile, unpack=True)
```

Some of these files are empty (I can't control that) and when that happens I get this warning printed on screen:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:795: UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "/path_to_file/file.dat"
  warnings.warn('loadtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)
```

How can I prevent this warning from showing?

Comment: Do you want to get an empty array in that case with no warning, or do you want to actually handle the warning as if it were an exception and do something different in those cases?

Comment: An empty list is enough, no fancy handling needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will have to wrap the line with `catch_warnings`, then call the `simplefilter` method to suppress those warnings. For example:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    data = np.loadtxt(myfile, unpack=True)
```

Should do it.

Comment: This will hide _all_ warnings in that line, not just the one you want… but that's probably fine, and since numpy doesn't seem to define warning categories there's good alternative. So, this seems like the best answer.

Comment: You can further hone it to only ignore UserWarnings if needed by using the more advanced `filterwarnings()` method. An example would be to replace the `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")` line with `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, append=1)`

Comment: It's strange but this is not working for me. I'm still seeing the warnings.

Comment: @MSalmo: Unfortunately, most warnings that don't come from specific parts of the language itself are `UserWarning`, so that only helps so much. It would be nice if numpy defined a new category instead of using the default, but… since they don't, and since you probably won't get any other warnings from this line of code, it's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious possibility is to pre-check the files:

```
if os.fstat(myfile.fileno()).st_size:
    data = np.loadtxt(myfile, unpack=True)
else:
    # whatever you want to do for empty files
```

Comment: Does not work if the file contains comments but no data.